# How can i extend magento 2 ListProduct Block class in any Php class and how can i used that?

Tags: magento2, blocks, product-list

```
class My_Catalog_Block_Product_List extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct
{

}

productTemplate = 'product.phtml';
$productList = new My_Catalog_Block_Product_List();
$productList->getItemHtml($productTemplate, $product);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class A extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface
     */
    protected $_layout;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface $layout
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
    ...
        \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface $layout,
        ...
    ) {
        ...
        $this->_layout = $layout;
        ...
    }

    /**
     * @return $this
     */
    public function getSomethingBlock()
    {
       return $this->_layout->getBlockSingleton(\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct::class);
    }
}
```